# MPG321 doesn't work when used with sudo

Tags: server, sound, raspberrypi, 23.10

I have a Raspberry Pi 4 running on Ubuntu Server and I have a problem with `mpg321` for some reason it doesn't work when ran it with `sudo`.
For example when I run :

```
mpg321 /path/sound.mp3
```

This works fine I can hear sound from my speaker that's connected with a jck 3.5mm and I get the following output :

```
High Performance MPEG 1.0/2.0/2.5 Audio Player for Layer 1, 2, and 3.
Version 0.3.2-1 (2012/03/25). Written and copyrights by Joe Drew,
now maintained by Nanakos Chrysostomos and others.
Uses code from various people. See 'README' for more!
THIS SOFTWARE COMES WITH ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY! USE AT YOUR OWN RISK!

Directory: /path
Playing MPEG stream from sound.mp3 ...
MPEG 1.0 layer III, 256 kbit/s, 44100 Hz joint-stereo

[0:03] Decoding of alert.mp3 finished.
```

But when I run it with sudo :

```
sudo mpg321 /path/sound.mp3
```

It doesn't work and here's what I get :

```
High Performance MPEG 1.0/2.0/2.5 Audio Player for Layer 1, 2, and 3.
Version 0.3.2-1 (2012/03/25). Written and copyrights by Joe Drew,
now maintained by Nanakos Chrysostomos and others.
Uses code from various people. See 'README' for more!
THIS SOFTWARE COMES WITH ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY! USE AT YOUR OWN RISK!

Directory: /path
Playing MPEG stream from sound.mp3 ...
MPEG 1.0 layer III, 256 kbit/s, 44100 Hz joint-stereo
Error opening unknown libao pulse driver. (Is device in use?)
```

I don't understand this behaviour.

And just to clear things out, the only reason why I’m trying to run this command with `sudo` is because I have a named pipe running as a systemctl service and a docker container, I'm trying to execute commands from my container to the host and using a named pipe, it does work except for `mpg321` that gives me the same bad output above even though I'm not using `sudo` but I noticed that on my host when I run it with sudo I get the same output so I thought maybe they're related.

Comment: They may be related, but more at a conceptual level I think (the containerization model of docker, versus sudo not having access to the desktop session's dbus). Are you starting the docker container with `--device /dev/snd`? see for example [ALSA or Pulseaudio sound in docker container](https://github.com/mviereck/x11docker/wiki/Container-sound:-ALSA-or-Pulseaudio#alsa-or-pulseaudio-sound-in-docker-container)

Comment: I’m quite the noob @steeldriver and I’m not sure what to do exactly. Do I just need to share the device on my docker compose file and test mpg321 again?

Comment: I'm more of a noob than you when it comes to docker - I don't have anything more to offer than the link I posted. You might want to change the focus (and title) of your question to attract the attention of docker folks.

Comment: I didn't understand most of them so I'm still facing the same issues. What I don't understand is why aplay & mpg321 don't work when used with sudo.